# Understand the group $\text{Ext}^1(k(x),k(x))$ from the derived categroy perspective

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex smooth projective variety and pick a skyscraper sheaf $k(x)$ on $X$ for some closed point $x$. We know that the group $\text{Ext}^1(k(x),k(x))$ meansures the first order deformation of $X$ near the point $x$. For example, we have
$$\text{Ext}^1(k(x),k(x))\cong T_xX$$
But on the other hand we know $\text{Ext}^1(k(x),k(x))=\text{Hom}(k(x),k(x)[1])$ in the derived category $D^b(X)$. So the elements are morphisms $k(x)\rightarrow k(x)[1]$.

What is the way to describe the morphisms $k(x)\rightarrow k(x)[1]$? Any reference or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: One way is the following: represent (locally) the point as a complete intersection, consider the Koszul resolution of its structure sheaf, then you can realize these maps as maps from the Koszul resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Here I expand Sasha's comment for me.

The question is local, so we can assume that $X$ is affine and of dimension $n$. In this case local coordinates near $x$ define a
section $s$ of $\mathcal{E}:=\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus n}$ vanishing transversely at $x$. We have the koszul resolution
$$0\rightarrow(\bigwedge^n\mathcal{E}^\vee\stackrel{s}{\rightarrow}\bigwedge^{n-1}\mathcal{E}^\vee\stackrel{s}{\rightarrow}\cdots\stackrel{s}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow k(x)\rightarrow0$$
So in $D^b(X)$ one has
$$k(x)\cong (\bigwedge^n\mathcal{E}^\vee\stackrel{s}{\rightarrow}\bigwedge^{n-1}\mathcal{E}^\vee\stackrel{s}{\rightarrow}\cdots\stackrel{s}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{O}_X)$$
As an example, when $n=1$ one has $k(x)\cong(\mathcal{O}_X\stackrel{s}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{O}_X)$. So the group $\text{Hom}(k(x),k(x)[1])$ can be roughly seen as the space of complex maps
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \mathcal{O}_X @>>> \mathcal{O}_X\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
\mathcal{O}_X @>>> \mathcal{O}_X  @>>> 0
\end{CD}$$